# Change color of Multibar chart in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, highcharts

I am using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) to represent some data and I've got stuck at this point:

I have the following chart:

[image]

How can I change the colors of each point of a bar ? ( e.g: instead of orange to set up 'red' ). Also, can I modify the color depending on the value of the point? (e.g: if the value is `> 2.5k` to transform that into another color).

My class looks like this:

```
class _TimeSeriesChart(_Chart):

    def get_options(self, series):
        return {
            'title': {
                'text': self.title,
            },
            'xAxis': {
                'type': 'datetime',
            },
            'yAxis': {
                'min': 0,
            },
            'plotOptions': {
                'series': {
                    'animation': True,

                },
                'column': {
                    'stacking': 'normal',
                    #'colorByPoint': True,
                },
            },
            'credits': {
                'enabled': False
            },
            'series': series,
        }
```

If `colorByPoint` is uncommented, I'll have each bar transformed in only one color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors can be set per point.

```
series: [{
  data: [{y: 1, color: '#ff0072'}, 
         ...
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbphxhfs/

Other option is to set `negativeColor` and `threshold`

```
series: [{
  negativeColor: 'red',
  threshold: 3,
  ...
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbphxhfs/1/

Colors can be also set for series (using color setting), or whole chart (using colors array).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbphxhfs/2/

Comment: I don't know how to make `colors: ['#f00','#0f0','#00f']` work in my django function. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Alexander `def get_options(self, series):
        return {
            'colors': ['#f00','#0f0','#00f']` is not working? Are you using any Highcharts wrappers? How is your function called?

Comment: I managed to make this working in the end. I have another question: How can I modify `Values` word from `yAxis` ?

Comment: This is a default yAxis title. You can modify it by changing text of title in yAxis options.